# Redirect after EndInvoke in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi have the following code on my view (JQuery):

```
$.post('<%=Url.Content("~/Customer/StartLongRunningProcess")%>');
```

Wich invokes an asynchronous call (C#):

```
public void StartLongRunningProcess()
    {

        ProcessTask processTask = new ProcessTask();
        processTask.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback(EndLongRunningProcess), processTask);
    }
```

Finally, the result of the call:

```
public void EndLongRunningProcess(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        ProcessTask processTask = (ProcessTask)result.AsyncState;
        string id = processTask.EndInvoke(result);


        RedirectToAction("~/SubscriptionList/SubscribedIndex/" + id);
     }
```

The redirect is ignored.  Response.Redirect also fails, since the HTTP headers has been already sent.  I've tried change the window.location from javascript, this works, but I'm unable to pass the parameter id by ViewData.  Any idea to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the headers have already been sent?  I'm not really up on asynchronous controllers, but I would doubt that it would start sending any headers right away.  My first thought would be that a redirect response to an ajax call isn't handled by the browser.  You will probably need to implement some logic that sends back a result with the URL and have your `success` delegate in jQuery look for that piece of data and then do the redirect through javascript (i.e. `window.location`).

HTH

Comment: Thank for your answer.  Actually the jquery post call is performed by a button.  At this moment the view was rendered by a controller. Trying Response.Redirect instead of Redirect results in an HttpException: "Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent".

Comment: And yes, I can store that id somewhere and get back for it later (i.e. in a database).  This is the part I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Even if the javascript is called because of a button click, it is still an ajax call, even according to jQuery documentation.  Also, RedirectToAction takes in an action name, not a virtual path, so while that may not be your immediate issue, it will be one before long.  I would suggest not sending a redirect, but sending a response that your `success` delegate can evaluate and determine what page to go to and use `window.location` to do the redirect client-side.